# What is header-data split and why it's needed for TCP_ZEROCOPY_RECEIVE page alignment?

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface, tcp

I'm currently investigating about [TCP_ZEROCOPY_RECEIVE](https://lwn.net/Articles/752188/) and I read that it requires header-data split support of NIC.
As far as I understand, this feature is to DMA the header (IP, TCP headers) and data (the rest) into the separated buffer. (for improve cache efficiency)
And for TCP_ZEROCOPY_RECEIVE, i understand that the data must be aligned to the page to map to the virtual address of the process.
My question is why does align data into pages require header data-split support of NIC. When network device driver creating sk_buff structures, can't it just read headers and copy data to a separately assigned page to perform zero copy?
Also I wonder how NIC drivers interact with NIC to utilize header-data split feature.

I'm sorry if my understanding is wrong, please let me know if there's anything to supplement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why does align data into pages require header data-split support of NIC. When network device driver creating sk_buff structures, can't it just read headers and copy data to a separately assigned page to perform zero copy?

For context, the headers must be separated from the data because (unprivileged) userspace can only be allowed to directly access the data.

The goal of zerocopy TCP receive is to involve exactly zero copies of data when receiving, all the way to userspace: when circumstances allow it, the NIC must DMA the packet into the area of userspace memory set up by the receiving process. If the driver has to copy data to split it, it’s no longer zerocopy.

See [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/752188/) [pair](https://lwn.net/Articles/754681/) of LWN articles for more details on the topic, and [this post by Jakub Kicinski](https://people.kernel.org/kuba/musings-on-zero-copy-tcp).